# how to select default database for odoo installation in odoo13 community version?

Tags: linux, postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

I have multiple database on my odoo13 like  database1, database2, database3, database4

Now what I want is it should select database1 by default when any users visit my website ...and also I must be able to select all other databases using this ->   http://mydomain/web/database/selector

I have tried

dbfilter=database1

in my odoo.conf  settings but it's not working ... Can anyone tell me how to do it ?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the **db_name** field instead. The others DBs will still be available from the selection menu.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply ....I tried  to use db_name field with database1,  but now only database1 is available in selection menu

Comment: Ok, thats is weird. What is in your dbfilter now ?. To list all available databases, i usually use `dbfilter = .* `  .